# Destination Host Unreachable when device is turned on on home network

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking

I have a home network consisting of an access point (leased from my internet provider) with IP address `192.168.2.1` with wifi disabled and dhcp enabled, connected to a router using an RJ45 cable. This router at `192.168.2.103` (Operation Mode:Access Point; TP-Link) has wifi enabled and dhcp disabled, and I have a laptop (A) connected to it with wifi and I can surf the net from the laptop, which has IP address `192.168.2.108`.

When I connect another laptop (B) to the network using wifi I can surf the net from it too, and it says it has IP address `192.168.2.203`. However, if I try to connect from A to B, say using `ping 192.168.2.203` I receive the error message "Destination Host Unreachable".

I have the same problem with my printer, in that whenever I switch it on, my laptop cannot find it. Same with a raspberry pi too. Both connecting using wifi.

After a while, my laptop can indeed connect. Why does it take so long for my laptop to be able to connect to the other devices?

If I try and print from my phone, I have the same problem.

OS Laptop A: Ubuntu 20.04
OS Laptop B: Windows 10
Printer: HP

The printer is configured at the access point (`192.168.2.1`) to use a static IP address, as is the raspberry pi.

Comment: It might work as well or better if you turn DHCP on the modem Off, connect a LAN port on your TP-link router to a LAN port on the modem, enable DHCP and a DHCP range on the TP-link router.

Comment: Is the printer's IP `192.168.2.1`? If so it has the same IP as the access point, this will cause a conflict. Also, your router is in AP mode, meaning routing capabilities are off. You shouldn't be able to surf the net unless something is missing in your explanation. Providing a diagram (including information about layer 1 and 3) might be helpful.